# Non Overlappings datetimes in two lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm making a personal project to return only the available slots that i have.
I have two lists, one with all the possible datetime slots and another list with all the block datetimes.

Right now I have the following code, but is returning the overlapping records (that is the opposite what i want)

So, what I'm doing wrong and what is the best approach?

(I search and i couldn't found anything related with the non overlapping datetimes)

The result should be something like this:

- 2018-09-01 05:00:00
- 2018-09-02 01:30:00

  class DateSpan
  {
      public DateTime StartDate;
      public DateTime EndDate;

  ```
  public DateSpan(DateTime start, DateTime end)
  {
      StartDate = start;
      EndDate = end;
  }

  public DateSpan(DateTime start, int duration)
  {
      StartDate = start;
      EndDate = start.AddHours(duration);
  }


  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var AvailableHours = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DateSpan>();
      AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 1, 5, 0, 0), 2));
      AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 4, 0, 0), 2));
      AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 5, 0, 0), 2));
      AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 1, 30, 0), 2));
      AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 4, 5, 0, 0), 2));

      var BlockTimes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DateSpan>();
      BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 1, 10, 0, 0), 2));
      BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 5, 0, 0), 2));
      BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 3, 5, 0, 0), 2));
      BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 4, 4, 0, 0), 2));

      var e = AvailableHours.SelectMany((DateSpan x) =>
      {
          var result = new List<DateSpan>();
          foreach (var o in BlockTimes.Where(y => x.StartDate < y.StartDate && y.StartDate < x.EndDate).ToList())
          {
              result.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(Math.Max(x.StartDate.Ticks, o.StartDate.Ticks)), new DateTime(Math.Min(x.EndDate.Ticks, o.EndDate.Ticks))));
          }
          return result;
      });
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: So, what result do you expect? What are available slots? For example, if you have 1 available slot from 2pm to 7pm and 1 blocking slot from 3pm to 4pm, should it return two slots: 2pm-3pm and 4pm-7pm?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev the result should be
2018-09-01 05:00:00
2018-09-02 01:30:00

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev in your example should return zero slots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a method in `DateSpan` class that will know how to determine whether two date spans intersect or not:

```
public bool Intersect(DateSpan other)
{
    return (this.StartDate >= other.StartDate && this.StartDate <= other.EndDate) ||
           (this.EndDate >= other.StartDate && this.EndDate <= other.EndDate);
}
```

Then, use this method to discover available time slots:

```
private List<DateSpan> GetNonOverlappingTimes()
{
    var AvailableHours = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DateSpan>();
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 1, 5, 0, 0), 2));
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 4, 0, 0), 2));
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 5, 0, 0), 2));
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 1, 30, 0), 2));
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 4, 5, 0, 0), 2));

    var BlockTimes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DateSpan>();
    BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 1, 10, 0, 0), 2));
    BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 5, 0, 0), 2));
    BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 3, 5, 0, 0), 2));
    BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 4, 4, 0, 0), 2));

    return AvailableHours.Where(x => BlockTimes.All(y => !x.Intersect(y))).ToList();
}
```

Comment: yours is giving me one extra slot that is wrong. the slot 2018-09-02 05:00:00 is in the block times. I think I have to change it to <= and >= right?

Comment: @piort Updated solution with >= and <= instead of > and <. Now it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarifications to your question, this seems to do the trick.  It uses a foreach loop instead of straight Linq, but to me this makes the code more readable and the solution more straightforward:

```
private List<DateSpan> GetNonOverlappingTimes()
{
    var AvailableHours = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DateSpan>();
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 1, 5, 0, 0), 2));
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 4, 0, 0), 2));
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 5, 0, 0), 2));
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 1, 30, 0), 2));
    AvailableHours.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 4, 5, 0, 0), 2));

    var BlockTimes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<DateSpan>();
    BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 1, 10, 0, 0), 2));
    BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 2, 5, 0, 0), 2));
    BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 3, 5, 0, 0), 2));
    BlockTimes.Add(new DateSpan(new DateTime(2018, 9, 4, 4, 0, 0), 2));

    var availableTimes = new List<DateSpan>();
    foreach (var avail in AvailableHours)
    {
        // check if there are any block times where the start date or end date is between the start date and end date of the available time
        bool isConflict = BlockTimes.Exists(bt => (bt.StartDate >= avail.StartDate && bt.StartDate < avail.EndDate) || (bt.EndDate > avail.StartDate && bt.EndDate <= avail.EndDate));

        if (!isConflict)
            availableTimes.Add(avail);
    }
    return availableTimes;
}
```

This gives the result that you said you expected.

Comment: In that case we should return zero slots. i just want to return the slots that don't overlap in the blocks list. Don't know if that make the question easy :)

Comment: @piort - see the revised answer - I didn't understand what you were trying to do at first.